# Regex is not matching in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I want to split up a camelCase string with spaces.

`"ClassicalMusicArtist" -> "Classical Music Artist"`

I should be able to do this by replacing `"/([a-z](?=[A-Z]))/g"` with `"$1 "` ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tV0yN8/1)).

But my regex is not getting any matches:

```
val regex = "/([a-z](?=[A-Z]))/g".r
val s = "ClassicalMusicArtist"

regex.replaceAllIn(s, "$1 ") // -> Returns "ClassicalMusicArtist"
regex.findFirstIn(s) // -> Returns None
```

What am I doing wrong? I used the regex in another language with success and can't figure out why I am not getting any matches.

Comment: No delimiters are necessary, look at [the docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

In scala the regex has to be `val regex = "([a-z](?=[A-Z]))".r` without the leading `/` and the modifier.

Comment: To be more precise, the `/` characters you often see in a regex are simply artifacts of the fact that other languages have regex literals, and they use the `/` as the quoting character for the literal.  They're not actually a part of the expression.